# Im using lubuntu with no dual boot, it has had a fatal crash and needs to be completely removed

Tags: installation, linux-mint, iso-image, uninstall, lubuntu

So my lubuntu OS v. Willey 14.04 has had a melt down the initial cause was a rewrite of the chown file and has grown from there, I can currently only access the terminal or an unusable desktop, I need to know how to completely remove lubuntu using its terminal as I'm on a PC without deul boot. And than I need to know how to install mint rather via same terminal or via the ISO disk I have preburned, please make answer s vey simple this is my first Linux and I've had it only 3 days I do not own a flash drive and am on a relatively stable wifi network, my first language is English but I live in Mexico, so my region would be that. The PC I'm working with is a 64 bit Intel HP notebook 15" display with Blu-ray ROM and HDMI I'm using a b and g connection. Unfortunately I don't know any of my other specs besides that I have 2 TB ram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to remove `Lubuntu` before installing `Linux Mint`. The installer can do that for you.

Just boot from the `Linux Mint` installation disk and start the installation of `Linux Mint`.

If you get to the part where it asks whether or not you are sure that you want to overwrite the existing data on the disk, answer `yes`. If the installer detects `Lubuntu` and suggests that it can keep it and make your system dual-boot, you can select to remove it.

This will get rid of `Lubuntu` and all of the other data on the disk as well. So make sure you have backed up everything you want to keep.

If your system doesn't boot from the disk, but instead always boots from the hard disk, you have to get into the boot menu of your laptop and change the boot order.
When you turn on on your laptop, it normally will tell you what key or key combination to press to get into the boot menu. It is often `Del`, `F2` or `F10`, but could be any key or key combination.

Good luck.

Comment: I have tried all of your mentioned with no luck, I've looked into boot order but can only do it from hard disk or from a flash drive, I live in Mexico and flash drives are not readily available or afordible here, I can get into the terminal by pressing shift + f-4 is there a way to do it through this, I've been able to get desktops but nothing else

Comment: If your laptop comes with a DVD/Blu ray player, it should be able to boot from it. According to http://support.hp.com/nz-en/document/c00364979 the optical drive should boot before the hard disk. The only way to install a new OS is to boot into an installation medium. It is not possible from a terminal, because the shell is running of the OS on your disk, which is going to be wiped when you install a new OS. The system will have to go through a reboot before you can install a new OS.

Comment: Thank you I punched my model number into HP's website it's f10 to get into BIOS from there I was able to install from the blu-ray-rom drive. You may mark this as solved

Comment: @user6232162. I can't mark the question as solved, you have to do that :-) If you are happy with my answer, then you can tick it as the one that solved your problem (click on the little green check-mark below the up-vote and down-vote arrows).